# Sending json requests to flask server in pytest

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I want to send a json with a POST request, to a specific endpoint to my server, in pytest.

This is what i normally feed the server with curl:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"item":"ZycugK6yXdHgf8foQTUnKY.txt","method":"one"}' 0.0.0.0:5000/convert
```

And this is how i tried to recreate it in pytest:

```
   data = {"item": filename, "method": method}
   response = client.post('/convert', content_type='application/json', data=data)
```

Where the filename, and method parameters are received as inputs to the function (forwarded by a decorator).

However, i keep getting a `400 - Bad Request`, which means that i am doing something wrong with my request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
data = {"item": filename, "method": method}
response = client.post('/convert', content_type='application/json', data=json.dumps(data))
```

You need to serialize the data.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the client you are using.
For `requests`, you could use simply

```py
response = client.post("/convert", json=data)
```